# Allow permission to edit only empty cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, permissions, cell

I try to create a shift schedule in Google Sheets.
Is there a way to set permissions for people to enter data, but not overwrite existing data?

The sheet is open for all employees and the employees can put theirself in the cell. But one time the cell is filled with a name, the other employees can not overwrite the name.

For example Employee1 put his name in the cell, Employee2 can not edit the cell. Only the creator of the sheet and Employee1 can. I have following code:

```
function onEdit(e){   
var protection = e.range.protect(); 
protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
 protection.setDomainEdit(false);   } }
```

Actually it is working, but one time a cell is filled and Employee1 clears the cell, Employee2 can not fill the cell although the cell is empty again.
Has somebody an idea?